# Find all combinations of numbers that sum to a target

Tags: r

I wish to find the speediest way to find up to 1000 possible combinations of 'n' integers to find a target integer.

For example.  Say I wanted to sum to the number '20'.   I want to find up to 1000 combinations of four integers that sum to this number. The integers can repeat themselves.  I also have a condition that the integer must not be smaller than a particular number, in this case 4.

```
target<-20  #the number I wish to sum to
lowest<-4   #the smallest integer I allow
size<-4 #the number of integers I wish to use to sum
maxposs <- target - ((size-1) * lowest) #given the lowest, this is the max possible integer. In my example it is 8.
```

This is how I have started to work this out.  Using `combn` to find all combinations of the four chosen integers and then filtering by those that sum to my target.

```
m <- combn(rep(lowest:maxposs,size), size)
m1<- m[,colSums(m)==target]
```

Here, 'm1' has 245 columns. There are only this many solutions.   The last few columns:

```
#     [,238] [,239] [,240] [,241] [,242] [,243] [,244] [,245]
#[1,]      4      4      4      4      4      4      5      5
#[2,]      5      5      5      6      7      4      6      4
#[3,]      7      4      5      4      4      5      4      5
#[4,]      4      7      6      6      5      7      5      6
```

However, in my real application, I can be dealing with very high integers (summing up to 1000) and want to limit myself to a random sample of 1000 possible combinations.   As this is for a randomization statistical test, speed is of the essence. I wonder if anyone knows of a faster way of doing this. My way doesn't feel intuitively quick.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `maxposs <- target - (size-1) * lowest`?

Comment: @cyberj0g - yes, I caught that after I posted

Comment: `combnPrim` from `library(gRbase)` would be [fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828301/faster-version-of-combn/26828486#26828486).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064675/generating-all-permutations-of-n-balls-in-m-bins

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
my_matrix <- matrix(nrow = 1000, ncol = 4)
i <- 1
nn <- 1000
while(i <= 1000){
  x <- sample(x = 4:nn, size = 3)
  y = nn - sum(x)
  if(y >= 4){
    my_matrix[i, ] <- c(x, y)
    i <- i + 1
  }
}
```

Per Gavin's suggestion, redone with a preallocated matrix. Now this runs in .158 seconds, twice as fast, and probably scales better.

Comment: You would make this quicker still if you didn't commit the cardinal sin of growing an object, a data frame no less, to compound the issue!, in a `for` loop. Allocate a matrix of 4 columns and 1000 rows. Fill in the `i`th row if it meets the criterion. For larger problems, the copying of the data frame will just kill performance.

Comment: noted and changed. I'm trying to break bad habits like that, but didn't think too much about it since it only took a half second anyway in this case.