# Function that outputs combinations with constraint

Tags: r

I wish to write a function that accepts two variables n and k, where n>k, and returns vectors composed out of the integer k. The function should return all possible vectors, where k is the largest number in the vector, and all of the elements in the vector sum to n. In short, what I want to accomplish is the following:

`n = 10, k = 3`
thus the vectors are as follow

```
(3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
(3,2,1,1,1,1,1)
(3,2,2,1,1,1)
(3,2,2,2,1)
(3,3,1,1,1,1)
(3,3,2,1,1)
(3,3,2,2)
(3,3,3,1)
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. Can you provide some of the things you've tried already? You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30858688/7856717) similar post for insights on how to find all possible combinations to a given sum.

Comment: Also please note that we reserve `Rstudio` tag for issues on the specific IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use package RcppAlgos for this:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
n <- 10
k <- 3

#loop over 1:n
res <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
  #generate all combinations of a vector with constraint
  x <- comboGeneral(k, i, TRUE, constraintFun = "sum", 
             comparisonFun = "==", 
             limitConstraints = n)
  #remove solutions that don't contain k
  x[as.logical(rowSums(x == k)),]

  })

res <- res[lengths(res) > 0]

res <- lapply(res, function(x) if (is.matrix(x)) asplit(x, 1) else x)

library(rlist)
list.flatten(res)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 3 3 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2 2 3 3
#
#[[3]]
#...
```

Comment: Is their a way to split the matrices in the output list into vectors, then the list only contains vectors and not both?

Comment: See the edit ...

Comment: I ran your code and saw that you have an error in your edited code; asplit => split. I changed the code and run it but my results differ from yours? $`1`
[1] 1 2 3 2 3 3 3 3

$`1`
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 2 3 3

$`1`
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 2 3 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 3

[[5]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3

>

Comment: No, that is not an error: [`asplit`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/asplit) was added in R 3.6.0. You should update R.

Comment: Now it works, thank you for your assistance, I appreciate it.

Comment: Feel free to click the check-mark next to the answer.