# Generate a list of all combinations of N integers summing to a number M

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

Looking to return a list of all ways of choosing N non-negative integers so that they sum to M

For instance if N = 3 and M = 2 this would return

```
[[1]]
[1] 0 0 2

[[2]]
[1] 0 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 0 2 0

[[4]]
[1] 1 0 1

[[5]]
[1] 1 1 0

[[6]]
[1] 2 0 0
```

Comment: `partitions::compositions(2, 3)`

Comment: Can you try `library(RcppAlgos);comboGeneral(seq_len(N), M, constraintFun = "sum", comparisonFun = "==", limitConstraints = N)`

Comment: @Henrik Thank you, but can't seem to get list output as desired (class = partition, which I'm not sure how to deal with)

Comment: @Elis `asplit` happily accepts the result: `x = compositions(2, 3)`; `asplit(x, 2)`. Or if you want perform an explicit coercion of the partition, first wrap the result in `as.matrix`.

Comment: You actually do not want combinations based on your example, you want permutations.

Comment: The duplicated answer doesn't return a list. See here for a solution that returns a list and doesn't require a package dependency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73252355/3614648