# Nested loops in R, all the possibilities

Tags: r, for-loop, nested

I need to make a data frame  that has all possibilities in which seven variables sum up 100, every variable could be 0 to 100.
I implement the following code but it takes to long.

```
combina <- function(U){
          d<- NULL
          for (i in 0:U) {
            for (j in 0:U) {
              for (k in 0:U) {
                for (l in 0:U) {
                  for (m in 0:U) {
                    for (n in 0:U) {
                      for (o in 0:U) {
                        if (i+j+k+l+m+n+o == U){
                          d <- rbind(d,c(i,j,k,l,m,n,o))
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        return(d)
        }
```

as you see, i used the U variable for tests and after the 15 it takes forever...

Comment: You should see about breaking out of each for loop when you get a sum above 100...

Comment: Seems like `expand.grid` or `combn` would provide a much easier way...though such a problem gets really difficult with large U.

Comment: This may seem like a simple task, but you're asking R to create and evaluate 100^7 (that's 100 trillion) different number combinations, each containing 7 numbers. It's a big task. I agree with @Laurel's suggestion to break the loop when a sum exceeds the target value, which would at least cut the size of the task down a little.

Comment: you should be looking at the [partitions package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partitions/index.html).  According to the `P()` function in that package, there are "only" about 190 million partitions, but computing them all could still be a big challenge.

Comment: @alistaire, I don't think so.  Those problems are about whether an appropriate sum exists, not about enumerating all such solutions.

Comment: Does order matter, e.g. is `10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20` different from `20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10`?

Comment: [The answers to this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275263/all-combinations-of-k-numbers-between-0-and-n-whose-sum-equals-n-speed-optimiza) might be helpful.

Comment: @alistaire yes it' matter every variable is independent, and it's has to pass through all the cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an R function that yields all sequences of k non-negative integers summing to n.

```
sum_to_N <- function (n, k) {
  combos <- combn(seq(0, n+k-2), k-1)
  as.data.frame(t(rbind(combos, as.integer(n+k-1)) - rbind(0L, combos+1L)))
}
```

Let's look at an example with smaller numbers. To find all solutions of 
A + B + C + D = 10 in non-negative integers, we start by finding all combinations of distinct numbers a < b < c between 0 and 12, then we set A = a, B = b - (a+1), C = c - (b+1), and D = 13 - (c+1). In general, to find all ways to write n as a sum of k integers, we start by finding all combinations of (k-1) distinct integers between 0 and n+k-2.

The number of solutions is (n+k-1) choose (k-1). In this case, n = 100 and k = 7, so the number of solutions is (106 choose 6) = 1,705,904,746. This is probably too many rows to fit in a data frame, so you should try to find an approach to your problem that does not involve storing all of the combinations.

Comment: The data frame would require 48 gigabytes (28 bytes per row). This is not outside the range of possibility, but it's hardly practical.

Comment: Dave thanks for the reply, you are right, i think i'll have to make another approach. Like you said it's hardly practical, specially if later i have to calculate a distance vector to it. Anyway, your solution was the answer, because i just run it, and works perfectly!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This is one way I can think of solving your problem (on a much smaller scale since I can't want to create 100^7 data). :)

For example, if you have four variables ranging from 0 - 10 and you want to find all combinations of them that add up to 10, here is how you can do:

```
df <- expand.grid(a = 1:10, b = 1:10, c = 1:10, d = 1:10)
df[rowSums(df) == 10, ]
```

The output has 84 combinations of values out of the 10,000 (10^4) passible values.

Of course, this solution looks simple, because it creates and stores the 10,000 x 4 data frame first. This gets to be a big problem as size increases.

- Edited per comment below. Agree, it is much better, and perhaps also more efficient than `apply`.

Comment: 100^7 seems a bit high. The specific number might depend on whether these need to be unique and whether they need to be positive. I think you should be asking for question clarification before jumping to a solution.

Comment: You can simplify the subsetting a bit: `df[rowSums(df) == 10, ]`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that i can't allocate the vector, because in my case it's size it would be of 372529 GB

Comment: Like I said, I was posting this as a way to show how the permutations work with expand.grid. 100 trillion sums alone is problem, let alone pre-storing in memory.

Comment: Sorry for my previous post, i was very rude, first of all, @Gopala thanks for the reply. i don't understand what do you mean by "let alone pre-storing in memory", thanks in advance for all the help